# OS Information of networkclient using C#

Tags: c#, networking, operating-system

I'm working on an application which scans a given networkrange for computers. From the found clients I need to get the IP, hostname, Mac address, OS Information etc.

Now, I have all of the above, except the OS version. Does anyone have a clue on how I could achieve this?

I'm stuck.

Thanks in advance, Christophe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use WMI, add reference to - System.Management dll and provide namespace, use following code with appropriate parameters-

```
 ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope();    
            try
            {                      

                ConnectionOptions conOptions = new ConnectionOptions();  

                options.Username = "<Provide username>";    
                options.Password = "<Provide password>";    
                options.EnablePrivileges = true;    
                options.Authority = "ntlmdomain:<domianname>";                        

                scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\<IP address/machine name>\root\CIMV2", options);

                scope.Connect();                      

                SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem");

                ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);

                using (ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection = searcher.Get())
                {    
                    foreach (ManagementObject m in queryCollection)
                    {                            

                        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Computer Name : {0}", m["csname"]));    
                         Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Windows Directory : {0}", m["WindowsDirectory"]));    
                         Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Operating System: {0}", m["Caption"]));    
                         Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Version: {0}", m["Version"]);

                         Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Manufacturer : {0}", m["Manufacturer"]));

                    }

                }

            }    

            catch (Exception ex)
            {


            }
```

You must have access right to steal this info else you will get Access right exception.

Comment: Thanks guys for the solutions, but Nmap didn't go that well.. Neither did the WMI solution as it needs the credentials to log in to the machine.

The point is an application that can be run from a laptop plugged in in a network, and the app should scan a given range and show the found computers in the network. So I assume there is no solution to this? As getting the credentials is impossible.

Thanks anyway! 

Christophe,

Answer (score 1):

You could run [Nmap](http://nmap.org/download.html) using `Process` class from `System.Diagnostics` and parse the result:

```
var process = new Process()
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
    {
        FileName = "cmd.exe",
        Arguments = "/c nmap -O -v targethost",
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true
    }
};
process.Start();

while (!process.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
{
    string line = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
    // here you can parse to obtain the operating system
}
```

Creating your own OS detector in C# would be hard but if you are interested in an overview of how it works you can find it in this Nmap chapter: [Chapter 8. Remote OS Detection](http://nmap.org/book/osdetect-usage.html)